# How to make a heavier math font?

Tags: math-mode, bold

I want to make a heavier math font by using the command \hm which is from bm package. But it doesn't work well and give a same font like the one made by \bm. Could you help me find out where the wrong is, or show me another way to make a heavier math font?

The following is the code and what I get:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,mathtools,bm}

\begin{document}
    
\[
    \hm{a} \quad \bm{a} \quad a
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\hm` requires a math font family supplied in three weights. The only case I know is the commercial mathtime family (for which `bm` was origially writen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because there are no heavy fonts for the `\hm` command in the default Computer Modern series. The following comes from [the documentation](https://mirrors.hit.edu.cn/CTAN/macros/latex/required/tools/bm.pdf) of the `bm` package.

*If there is a ‘heavy’ math version defined (usually accessed by a user-command \heavymath) then a similar command \hm is defined which access these ‘ultra bold’ fonts. Currently this is probably only useful with the ‘mathtime plus’ font collection.*

Note that 'hm' is a short hand for 'heavy math font' which has a bigger line weights than 'bold math font' abbreviated as 'bm'.